# UserForm data saved to worksheet and word document and hyperlink to be added to cell

Tags: excel, hyperlink, vba

When the “Submit” button is clicked, the Userform data is being saved into the next available row in sheet3 and a word document is created and saved into a specific folder.

At the same time, how can I add a hyperlink of the word document file name just created and insert hyperlink in column H? Can it be added to the code below?
Please can someone help?

```
SaveName = "\Desktop\DAILY REPORT" & Format(Now, "dd-mmm-yyyy") & FileExt
If .Version <= 12 Then
           .ActiveDocument.SaveAs SaveName
        Else
           .ActiveDocument.SaveAs2 SaveName
        End If
          .ActiveDocument.Close
        .Quit
        Set wdApp = Nothing      
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes. You might set a hyperlink. The following code may serve as a rough guide. The key point is that you need to supply a row number for the cell in column H in which you wish to place the hyperlink. There are more faults in the code because you supplied only a fraction of your procedure. The intention is to show how you can program the hyperlink.

```
Private Sub SetHyperlink()

    Const C As Long = 8                 ' = Column H

    Dim Wdapp As MSWord.Application
    Dim SaveName As String
    Dim Ws As Worksheet
    Dim Rng As Range
    Dim R As Long

    Set Ws = ActiveSheet                ' change as required
    R = Ws.Cells(Ws.Rows.Count, "H").End(xlUp).Row + 1
    ' the path of SaveName is incomplete:
    ' must start with drive (like C:\Users\[Username]\Desktop)
    ' or Environ("USERPROFILE") & "\Desktop
    SaveName = "\Desktop\DAILY REPORT" & Format(Now, "dd-mmm-yyyy") & FileExt

    Set Rng = Ws.Cells(R, C)
    Ws.Hyperlinks.Add Anchor:=Rng, _
                      Address:=SaveName, _
                      TextToDisplay:="Choose your text", _
                      ScreenTip:="Click to open the file"

    With Wdapp
        If .Version <= 12 Then
           .ActiveDocument.SaveAs SaveName
        Else
           .ActiveDocument.SaveAs2 SaveName
        End If

        .ActiveDocument.Close
        .Quit
    End With

    Set Wdapp = Nothing
End Sub
```

Comment: Hi Variatus, 
Thank you so much for your help. I'm sorry for the confusion caused by suppling only a fraction of my procedure and for the incomplete path of SaveName. My procedure is so long that I was unsure how best to shorten it. I’ve managed to modify and incorporate your code into my procedure and it’s working. The only problem is with R = 12 because it adds hyperlink file always to row # 12. I need the hyperlink to be added on the last empty row of column H. Please advise how to achieve this?

Comment: I'll try by changing R = 12 to R = Sheet3.Rows("3").End(xlDown) + 1. Hopefully it will work.

Comment: Great! I'm glad you got it working. In the code above, I have replaced the arbitrary "12" with the first blank cell found in column H. BTW, rather than creating endless procedures, I recommend to isolate each logical step in its own sub or function which can be called from a "Main". That works to simplify trouble-shooting.